# Hibernate mapping and sql script issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two classes. I don't understand. How can to map 'fromUser' and 'toUser' on 'User' class?
What should I add to SQL?

Please advise me a book about Hibernate and SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE message
            (
                id LONG NOT NULL,
                fromUser LONG NOT NULL,
                toUser LONG NOT NULL,
                primary key (id)
            );

 CREATE TABLE user
            (
            id LONG NOT NULL,
            primary key (id)
            );
@Entity
    @Access(FIELD)
    public class Message {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
        @Id
        private Long id;       

        private User fromUser;

        private User toUser;
    }


    @Entity
    @Access(FIELD)
    public class User {
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
        @Id
        private Long id;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add relation mappigs like `@OneToOne, @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany`. That depends on your db relationship between.
As you want to have `User` FK in your `Message` entity, you `Message` mapping should be like this:

```
@Entity
    @Access(FIELD)
    public class Message {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
        @Id
        private Long id;       

        @ManyToOne
        private User fromUser;
        @ManyToOne
        private User toUser;
    }
```

as for SQL you should add FK constraints to the User entiy.

Before you will read about "Hibernate and SQL" start with only relational SQL engines, as you don't have basic knowlage about relations I suppose (no hard feelings please).